# XSS Vulnerabilities Issue in a Servlet Class for response.getOutputStream().write(buffer)

Tags: java, servlets, xss

I am fixing issues against the code audit report for my module. The issue is XSS VULNERABILITIES.
It has reported issue at the syntax
response.getOutputStream().write(buffer);
How to fix it ?
I have done sufficient home work and found that ESAPI recommended by OWASP can help me to fix it, but how to implement it ? The issue is in a servlet class ?
or any other api or anything else could help me to fix it?
please share you relevant experience.

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
        FileInputStream fileInuptStream =null;
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =null;
        try{
           ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
            File attachmentDir = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("")+File.separator+"Reports" );
            String uploadDir=attachmentDir.getPath();
            if (!attachmentDir.exists()) {
                attachmentDir.mkdirs();
            }

            HSSFWorkbook wb= new HSSFWorkbook();
             AAAA  aaa=new AAAA();          
            wb=aaa.getExportXLS(request, response, fileName, wb);
             if(request.getSession().getAttribute("SESSION_AAAAA")!=null){
                    request.getSession().removeAttribute("SESSION_AAAAA");
            }           
              fos=new FileOutputStream(uploadDir+File.separator+fileName);
            wb.write(fos);

            File fileXls=new File(uploadDir+File.separator+fileName);
              fileInuptStream = new FileInputStream(fileXls);
              bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInuptStream);
              byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int start = INT_ZERO;
            int length = ONE_ZERO_TWO_FOUR;
            int offset = MINUS_ONE;
            byte [] buffer = new byte [length];
            while ((offset = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, start, length)) != -1)
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, start, offset);


            buffer = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            response.setContentType("application/xls");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName );
            response.setContentLength((int ) fileXls.length());
            response.getOutputStream().write(buffer);  --- REPORTED AT THIS LINE
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

Comment: Without code it is hard to determine what needs to be changed...  Your problem might be better served if you post some code.

Comment: What is the context? I cannot believe that they (the tool) just complained about this one line of code?

Comment: @home: It can, if you just write a piece of html code to the output stream without taking into account escaping of dynamic data you can get in trouble.

Comment: @tom: I agree, that's what I meant by 'context'.

Comment: The audit report says that at line no having the syntax response.getOutputStream().write(buffer); is xss vulnerable. the reports has the message "Injection of data from a file ("buffer") to servlet response (possible XSS attack)". the java class is a servlet for exporting the report format in xls format. the code of the method having the above syntax is below

Comment: the code is above in the post.i know that ESAPI can help me out and but it is for the implementation at the client side. how to fix this one in jacva code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to validate the input and output as request is directly taken as input in the method. use ESAPI to validate the buffer field using getValidatedFileContent() from ESAPI. validate the fileName field for the fileName Injection attack. Also any filed that is taken as output from the method having request as input should be validated strictly.

Comment: some code would help

Answer (score 1):

This is a false warning. This servlet is returning a XLS file which is created by Apache POI, not a HTML document. There can impossibly be means of a XSS attack.

This code is however rather clumsy and inefficient. It is creating a file in the expanded WAR folder (which would get lost anyway when the WAR get redeployed) and then it's copying its entire content fully into server's memory, instead of writing to the response directly. Probably this clumsy approach has confused the audit tool. You should just be passing `HttpServletResponse#getOutputStream()` to `Workbook#write()` instead.

Here's a full rewrite based on the code posted so far:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
AAAA aaa = new AAAA();          
wb = aaa.getExportXLS(request, response, fileName, wb);
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setContentType("application/xls");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: ya, you are correct. but it was the requirement. but now the point is how to convince it is not xss vulnerable as the audit report says that.

Comment: its a case of file download injection and can I use the method ESAPI.httpUtilities().SetHeader("Content-Disposition",
"attachment; filename=" + fn );?